# Cisco Catalyst cluster heartbeat switch issue - increasing input errors

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst

PROBLEM:
The servers in two clusters keep losing heartbeat connectivity with each other thus causing database outages.  Outages are brief but disruptive.

SETUP:

- There are two clusters of three servers each.
- Each server has one NIC connected to a single Layer 2 switch (Catalyst 2950) with the switch ports hard-coded at 100Mb/full-duplex.
- The DBAs confirm that each heartbeat NIC is hard-coded to 100Mb/full-duplex.
- There are two clusters configured in VLAN 100 and in the same subnet (10.40.60.0/24).
- The management IP address is on a separate subnet (10.40.1.0/24) and it's switch port is in VLAN 1.

SYMPTOMS:

- I see an ever-increasing error count on the switch ports.  For the three servers in one cluster the input errors (all CRC) are about 3% of total input packets.  There are no output errors.  The other cluster is at about 6% of total input packets.
- Transmit and receive load on the switch ports is light, under 20/255 on txload and rxload.
- The switch log shows the switch ports bouncing:

> May  16 11:15:31 PDT: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/13, changed state to down
>   May  16 11:15:32 PDT: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/13, changed state to down
>   May  16 11:15:34 PDT: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface FastEthernet0/13, changed state to up
>   May  16 11:15:35 PDT: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface FastEthernet0/13, changed state to up
>   
>   TROUBLESHOOTING STEPS PERFORMED:

- I replaced the old Cat5 cabling between the server heartbeat NIC and the switch with new Cat6 -- no effect.
- I created a new VLAN 200 in a new subnet (10.40.61.0/24) and had the DBAs re-IP their heartbeat NICs on one cluster -- no effect.
- We tried every combination of speed and duplex on the switch port and the NIC -- no effect, went back to 100Mb/full-duplex on both.
- The DBAs upgraded the Broadcom drivers on both clusters to the latest -- drop in error percentage on the 6% cluster down to 4%, the other cluster is still at 3%.

MY PROPOSED NEXT STEPS:

- There are Intel NICs on the servers. Try moving the cluster heartbeat to an Intel NIC. Maybe it's a Broadcom issue?
- Change out the switch to a gig capable switch.  There is a Catalayst 3560x available, but taking it will delay a project.  Maybe gig on the switch port and NIC will play nicer?

THOUGHTS?

Is there something I can configure on the existing 2950 switch to mitigate the errors?  What additional troubleshooting steps should I take?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CRC errors are often cabling problems. Here are the things I would check next before swapping out hardware:

- Are the servers connected directly to the switch or do they connect through some sort of infrastructure cabling?  If so, get the infrastructure cables re-certified.
- If you have a real cable tester (not a simple continuity tester), I would test the cables.
- If the cables are hand made, I would replace with factory made cables.  Often run into these types of issues with hand made cables.
- Check to see if there is any source of EM near where the cables run.  Re-path the cables if you can even temporarily to make sure they are kept separate from power or other sources of EM.

Beyond that, I would start at the NICs as you already indicated.  Could be you got some from a bad run.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend testing by moving to the Intel NIC as you have proposed. I have run into similar issues where a small percentage of the traffic was input errors. We trouble shot the problem by placing a dumb hub between server (in my case it was cameras) and the switch. If the switch no longer sees any input errors then the problem is the server NIC.

I tried many of the same steps that you have proposed. In my case it turned out to be a bad manufacturing run. The only thing that corrected the issue was replacing the NIC (cameras).